# How to find last alphabet in a string using c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, preg-match

I want to find out the last alphabet in a string in c# .net. For instance, I have `1234B0097D576676` and I need to find `D`. Same as in `0103D0001Y000001`, the result should be `Y`.

To do this there is a function in PHP `preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z]+$/', $scanned_code, $match);`. This will return the last occured character in the string. How can we do the same in c# .net? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i would choose a linq soultion

```
string chars = "1234B0097D576676";
char Result = chars.LastOrDefault(x => Char.IsLetter(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a positive lookahead in the regex `[a-z](?=[^a-z]*$)` with `Ignorecase` option to get that last letter.

```
var txt1 = "0103D0001Y000001";
var regex1 = new Regex(@"[a-z](?=[^a-z]*$)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase  | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
var c1 = regex1.Matches(txt1).Cast<Match>().Select(d => d.Value.Trim()).ToList();
```

Output:

[image]